# abstract classes and constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, abstract-class

I read this question "[C++ Abstract Class: constructor yes or no?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808667/c-abstract-class-constructor-yes-or-no)" and the answers belonging to it.

But according to answers, I understand that we need the constructor to initialize it data members, however I can use its member functions like setter functions in **my derived class** to initialize the data members, so Why is it important to define a constructor?

Comment: The constructor (if called) guarantees the correct initial state of the object. Setters might never be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default constructor definition and the member initializations make the class *self contained* regarding proper setup conditions (valid state).
Usage of setter methods to manipulate the class instance is optional for class clients (**including inheriting classes**).

You may consider adding more constructor signatures, that the clients can use to inititialze the class members with a single call, and don't require these applying additional setter calls.

It depends on the particular use case, what's more convenient and semantically correct in the end.

Comment: Yes, adding more constructor signatures will be useful for the clients if they are going to create objects but in case of abstract classes no way to create objects.

Comment: @M_E Abstract classes are intended to be inherited, so what are you bothering about? If you want to have pure abstract interfaces, don't introduce data members (but rather virtual getter/setter methods) at all!

Comment: @M_E: A derived constructor _can and does_ call the constructor of a pure virtual base class. Always.

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons:

1. To ensure the objects are always within a valid state.
2. You need a copy constructor to ensure that data gets copied correctly (e.g., no blind copies of dynamically allocated resources).

Probably more.